# Django management command not capturing command line arguments

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run a Django management command with some optional arguments. The relevant code is below.

```
def add_arguments(self, parser):
    parser.add_argument('--from-date', type=str, help='Some help text')
    parser.add_argument('--to-date', type=str, help='Some help text')
    parser.add_argument('--from-type', type=str, help='Some help text')
    parser.add_argument('--until-type', type=str, help='Some help text')

def handle(self, *args, **options):
    from_date = options.get('from-date')
    to_date = options.get('to-date')
    from_type = options.get('from-type')
    until_type = options.get('until-type')
```

When I try to run the command in the terminal as follows, the arguments aren't being picked up.

```
python manage.py [NAME OF COMMAND] --from-date 2020-04-02 --to-date 2020-04-03
```

Why is this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [argparse docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#dest) have the answer. Your arguments will be available in `options` with the hyphens replaced by underscores

```
from_date = options.get('from_date')
```

Comment: aha! Thank you very much.